# calling css.gz in asp.net not working IIS

Tags: css, iis, asp-classic, gzip

I'm trying to call css.gz file in asp.net with this code:

```
<link href="items_list.min.css.gz" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I enabled static/dynamic compression files and gzip compression in IIS.
I tried to google but I can't find any help.
I'm probably doing something wrong but I'm not sure what.

Comment: I assume you have manually compressed css file and kept it in your application. If that is case then you need to check MIME type *.gz is registered with IIS.

Comment: Hi, It's registered but still not working.

Comment: U must have 

Content-Type:text/css 

in Response header
Do U ?